# Making a footer of fixed height for all pages in html and css

Tags: html, css, footer

I have been designing a website using html and css, for which i have made a footer. 
the code for the footer is as follows:

```css
footer {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.footrow {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111;
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-image: url('../images/footer.jpg');
}

.footrow2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #002c42;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 48px;
}

.foot {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.foot-p {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #66e355 !important;
  margin: 15px;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1px;
}

.quarter-width {
  width: calc(25% - 30px);
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

#social2 {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sc-icn2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footrow">
    <div class="foot">
      <div class="quarter-width">
        <p style="color:#fff;">Address</p>
        <hr>
        <div>
          Science & Technology University
          <hr> Phone: 02-7458745
          <hr> Email: <a href="mailto:registrar@abc.gmail.com">registrar@abc.gmail.com</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quarter-width">
        <p style="color:#fff;">Quick Links</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="">Link 1</a><br>
        <a href="">Link 2</a><br>
        <a href="">Link 3</a><br>
      </div>
      <div class="quarter-width">
        <p style="color:#fff;">Follow Us</p>
        <hr>
        <div id="social2">
          <div class="sc-icn2">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/social/facebook.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="facebook" title="fb"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="sc-icn2">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/social/twitter.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="twitter" title="@board"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="sc-icn2">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/social/instagram2.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="instagram" title=" Photography"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quarter-width">
        <p style="color:#fff;">Report</p>
        <hr>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="feedClick('bug')">Found 
a Bug</a><br>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="feedClick('feed')">Feedback</a><br>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="feedClick('feature')">Request feature</a><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footrow2">
    <div class="foot">
      <div class="half-width">
        <p class="foot-p">&copy;- 2018 | All rights reserved</p>
      </div>
      <div class="half-width">
        <p style="float:right !important;" class="foot-p">Developed &amp; Maintained By <a style="color:orange" href="https://www.facebook.com/abc"><strong>SK Biswas</strong></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The footer has two parts. one is within class "footrow" and another is within "footrow2". footrow will take position above footrow2. the problem is the height of the content of footrow2 class is taking different height for different pages. Is there any way to make it of a fixed height?

Comment: When I run the code in a snippet the footrow2 seems to have 100% width. The problem is probably with code unrelated to the footer itself.

Comment: Also, a **minimal** demo would be ideal. There's *waaay* too much irrelevant code here.

Comment: the problem is regarding height of the footer. I have corrected my post. Is there any solution? @Maharkus

Comment: Add a runnable script to your code. So that it will be easy for us to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give any element 100% width of your page better use the vw instead of % as:

```
width: 10vw;
```

vw stands for viewport width and 10 means 100%. It will set the complete width on all devices.

Comment: the problem is regarding height of the footer. I have corrected my post. Is there any solution? @Rajat Jain